# Phaser 2 sprite detect border?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

for college I have to create a game, my game involves falling objects. But I cannot figure out how to *lose a life* when the object goes out of bounds.

Heres some of my code:

```
//my variables
var player;
var lives;
var max_lives = 3;
var objects;

var totalLife
var lifeText;
var totalScore;
var scoreText;

var inputs;

//creates the group for the objects
objects = this.add.group();
this.physics.enable(objects, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
objects.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
objects.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);

//spawns object
spawnObject: function () {
    var random = this.rnd.integerInRange(0, 25);
    if (random === 0) {
        var randomX = this.rnd.integerInRange(0, this.world.width - 150);
        var object = objects.create(randomX, -50, 'object');
        this.physics.enable(object, Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
        object.body.velocity.y = this.rnd.integerInRange(200, 300);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sprites fire an event when they leave the world bounds. Listen for it to drop one life.

Enable the event being emitted using:

```
sprite.checkWorldBounds = true;
```

Then, you can listen for:

```
sprite.events.onOutOfBounds
```

...and react to it by dropping one life.